# How to get the Accordion in ASP.Net Ajax Toolkit to resize?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, html, accordion, toolkit

Does anyone have any ideas how to get the Accordion control in the ASP.Net Ajax Control Toolkit to automatically resize so that it fills the DIV element it is contained in, and will react to that element being resized?

Thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried setting upp a sample application with an Accordion without any CSS and it's actually growing with the content by default. My guess is that you're using CSS that is limiting the growth in some way. Try using min-height instead of height for example and see if that solves it. If stuff like that won't work I'd suggest you post the CSS you use.

Comment: I can get it to grow with content, but what I actually want it to do is take up the entire size of it's parent DIV element which marks a space on the page for the Accordion.

Comment: If I understand this you need to set either a fixed height on the Accordion style, or 100% height and width.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can put it inside a div with height 100% and there is a property for the accordion AutoSize="Fill". Hope it works.